# plot axis rotate

Tags: rotation

im trying to plot a function in specific range where the function is negative.

this is what i get:

```
Plot[(f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

how can i flip the y axis to point downwards?
also, there is an option to see the positive y axis however my function does not have any positive value?

thanks!

Comment: Have you seen `Plot's` documentation? Take a look at Options / PlotRange and ScallingFunctions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the option [`ScalingFunctions->"Reverse"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html).